# Fix Google showing different language because of hyperlink options

Tags: localization, google-books

If I click on a link like https://books.google.it/books?id=_b8NAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA317&dq=%22dutch%20defence%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CFMQ6AEwB2oVChMIlvGX3cb1xgIVAlkUCh0C-ApT#v=onepage&q=%22dutch%20defence%22&f=false , the page displays info in Italian, presumably because of query string containing `hl=it`. Apart from manually editing the URL to have `hl=en`, which feels like a hacky approach to me, how can I make it display in my default language?

Comment: Just an educated guess, so take it with a grain of salt, but I doubt that you can do this. The whole point of the URL parameter is to _enforce_ its value.

Comment: Also, the page gets displayed in Italian _also_ because the site is a regional one (i.e. `.it`). And you get redirected to it because of Google’s cookies you already have in your browser.

Comment: @Alex removing the parameter `&hl=it` makes the page be displayed in the user default language even if the local domain is a from a different country.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Remove `&hl=it` from the URL.

## Explanation

The `ht=it` tells to the Google Books app to override the default language setting by using Italian.

The same apply to almost all the Google apps.

## References

[Meaning of Parameters in a Google Query - Google Operative System (Unofficial Blog)](http://googlesystem.blogspot.mx/2006/07/meaning-of-parameters-in-google-query.html)